# django-tables2: linkify, how to make target new window

Tags: django-tables2

Using the linkfy argument as so:

```
def linkify_sale(**kwargs):
    record = kwargs.get("record")
    if record:
        return f"https://...url...#{record.get('order_sale_id')}"

class ASA_Journal_ViewTable(tables.Table):
    ...
    order_sale_nbr = tables.Column(verbose_name="Sales Order Number", linkify=linkify_sale)
```

works. But how to I specify a target on the link, to open in a new window?

Answer (score 2):

ok, like this

```
 order_sale_nbr = tables.Column(verbose_name="Sales Order Number", linkify=linkify_sale, attrs={"a":{
        "target":"_blank"}})
```